# Binding to properties of viewmodel from datatemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Sample">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in my main window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Sample}"/>
</Grid>
```

Now how can I make the binding work? My window has set the datacontext to my viewmodel so I thought it would work but nothing. I dont see it applying the text.

My viewmodel has a normal property:

```
public string Data { get; set; } = "Hello World";
```

but I dont see it.

Here my mainwindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now my viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel {
  public string Data {get; set;} = "Hello World";
}
```

The entire code is kept very minimalistic for demonstration purposes.

**EDIT**:

Its still not working, this time to keep things simple:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string Data { get; set; } = "Hello World";



public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

Not working, I dont get it. It doesnt make sense does it? Ive set up the xaml just like explained by clemens.

Comment: @Clemens testet that as well, doesnt work.

Comment: @Clemens sure will do

Comment: @Clemens sorry forgot to copy that part. It doesnt work either. Its extremely weird. No error messages though.

Comment: are you sure you have the correct URL to the resource dictionary?

Comment: @MikeT You would get an exception.

Comment: @MikeT yep I do

Comment: @Clemens absolutely positive. It seems visual studio is playing a bit crazy every now and then. After a restart everything was fine...

Comment: @Clemens only if the incorrect url failed to resolve, and as your code suggestion should have fixed it, it was the only point of failure that hadn't been explored

Comment: @MikeT you make a point

Comment: @Asperger while there is nothing incorrect with setting the datacontext in the code behind i would suggest doing it in the XAML `<Window.DataContext><local:ViewModel /></Window.DataContext>` it keeps the code all in one place
`

Comment: @MikeT may I ask why? Just wondering. I will do that

Comment: @Asperger its just always a good idea to keep the code together so if the only thing your code behind is doing is setting the datacontext  then its easy to miss if you need to change things say having the datacontext passed from a parent

Comment: @MikeT Even if the URL could be resolved, you would still get an exception from the missing static resource, or if that could also be resolved, perhaps that it's not a DataTemplate.

Comment: @Asperger It does not matter at all if you set the DataContext in XAML or in code behind. Both approaches are perfectly valid. In most case the correct choice is just a matter of taste.

Comment: @Clemens only advantage I see for the code behind version is in case we want to create the view dynamically in code behind and want to inject the viewmodel py passing it through the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also set the ContentControl's Content property, like shown below.

In addition to that, you should include Dictionary.xaml via `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`, because it would allow to have additional "local" resources.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Sample}" Content="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hello Clemens you can have a look now. Added the entire procedure. I was thinking if id have to do this inside a "Loaded handler". Like notify that the property changed.

Comment: Hmm somehow it doesnt work. Really weird. going to try again

Comment: Im going to post the code. Somehow this doesnt work. Its still showing as empty.

Comment: As you can see, now ive tried setting the datacontext to my view directly (although it doesnt really matter). It doesnt work. Im thinking maybe i need to trigger this through some event.

Comment: For testing purposes ive set up a new wpf project but I can try again

Comment: It works. No idea what made it magically work now. Ive restarted visual studio.

Comment: @Clemens you don't have to use the MergedDictionaries aslong as the only resource you want are in that dictionary file, that is only required if you want to merge the Source dictionary to the local one, though i agree best practice to merge instead of replace

Comment: @MikeT Sure, that's why I wrote OP "should" do it. It is however always better, because you can still have "local" resources.

Comment: ah i think i still had your pre edit version on screen